# Reference a c++ dll in objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am a c# developer trying to learn objective c. I want to create a c++ dll using visual studio, that would handle certain parts of my application/game like movement calculations. My question is can objective c reference a c++ dll compiled in a windows platform, or any platform for that matter.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the 3rd party link, but this seems to be a relatively thorough discussion of this question http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective C works fine with C and C++ libraries, but they need to be generated for the specific platform (building for iPhone? Your libraries need to be built in the same environment).

x86 Windows DLLs will not work, though, because iOS does not support the x86 architecture and uses shared libraries instead of DLLs as a supported library format.